# Problema con la funcion str() en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

estoy creando una clase en Python, éste es el código:

```py
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self,name,balance=0.0):
        self.log=("Account Created!")
        self.name=name
        self.balance=balance
    def getBalance(self,balance):  #Getter for balance
        self.log("Balance checked at" + str(self.balance))
        return self.balance
    def setBalance(self,newBalance): #Setter for balance
        self.log("Balance changed to" + str(newBalance))
        self.balance=newBalance
    def log(self,message): #Logging method
        myLog=open("Log.txt","a")
        print(message, file=myLog)
        myLog.close()
```

El problema es que cuando hago

```
myBankAccount.setBalance(20.0)
```

Me sale el siguiente error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`
Agradezco a quién pueda ayudarme, estoy empezando con la POO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando inicializas el objeto, en:

```
def __init__(self,name,balance=0.0):
    self.log=("Account Created!")
```

Estas haciendo que `self.log` sea una cadena, un `str`. Por lo tanto, cuando la utilizas después, donde te marca el error, ahora usas eso que se declaró como una cadena como si fuera un `callable`, es decir, un objeto que tiene el método `__call__`, etc., puesto que la utilizas así.

```
self.log("Balance changed to" + str(newBalance))
```

Lo que quizás debiste haber hecho es, desde la inicialización, llamar al método `log` mas no asignar el atributo `log`.

```
self.log("Account Created!") # <-- Esto
self.log=("Account Created!") # <-- En lugar de esto
```

Con eso queda ese problema resuelto. Sin embargo, hay otro problema en el mismo método `log`, sé que no es el tema principal pero es que usas la función `print` para escribir en un archivo. Te recuerdo que en tu pregunta pusiste el tag `python2.7` y en esa versión de python no existe la clave `file` dentro de `print` pero si existe en las versiones de python3+.

Si es de verdad en python2.7, tendrías que haber puesto, por ejemplo.

```
with open("Log.txt","a") as myLog:
    myLog.write(message)
```

Si es python3+, funcionará perfecto.

Comment: Tienes razón en lo que la etiqueta, no es python 2.7. La cambiaré, por cierto esto resuelve el problema, Muchas gracias

Comment: Vale. Si mi respuesta te sirvió, harías un buen acto marcándola como la respuesta correcta.
Y por otro lado, tal vez te puede interesar que python tiene setters, getters y deleters usado el decorador @property. Te sugiero que les des una revisada.